# IMAP_SEARCH with multiple body keywords

Tags: php, imap

I have been looking online and haven't found another question exactly like this. What I want is to search a mailbox to find all emails containing X keywords. The amount of keywords is dynamic, and it does not need all of them. For example I want to search the inbox with keywords: PHP and JAVA. Meaning my ideal result would be that it returns emails which at least have 1 of the 2 keywords. Af of now I can search the body but am only able to pass 1 parameter. When I add another it seems to require both.

Here is some code:

```
$queryString = 'BODY "php" BODY "java"';


private function connectSmtp()
{
    $this->connection = imap_open(
        '{'.$this->credentials['smtp'].'/'.$this->credentials['encryption'].'}/'.$this->credentials['mailbox'],
        $this->credentials['user'],
        $this->credentials['password']
    );
}

private function readMailbox($queryString)
{
    $in = [];
    $totalMessages = \imap_num_msg($this->connection);//Used for something else

    $sorted = imap_search($this->connection, $queryString);

    for($i = 0; $i <= (count($sorted ) - 1); $i++) {
        $in[] = array(
            'index'     => $i,
            'header'    => \imap_headerinfo($this->connection, $sorted[$i]),
            'body'      => \imap_body($this->connection, $sorted[$i]),
            'structure' => \imap_fetchstructure($this->connection, $sorted[$i]),
            'mailnumber' => $sorted[$i]
        );
    }
    return $in;
}
```

However this returns a total of 220 emails, but when I search for just PHP I get 35000 (which is correct) and when I search for just JAVA I get 3000.

How can I fix this so I get all emails that at least contain 1 keyword and does not require all of the keywords to be in the email?

I also tried using: 
`$queryString = 'OR BODY "php" BODY "java" ';`
This returns false to me.

Comment: `or body foo body bar`. The or is prefix with two arguments, so for three terms you can use `or body foo or body bar body baz`, or `or or body foo body bar body baz`.

Comment: Making it like: 'OR BODY "php" BODY "sql" ' returns false for me.

Comment: What is your server software?  Unofrutnately, there is a lot of software that doesn't implement the IMAP query language well.  For an OR query, you can always just do multiple queries and union the results.

Comment: Its a microsoft exchange server, as far as I know this should have full query support. Also the multiple calls wont exactly be a solution since the mailbox has over 45.000 emails, this will greatly kill performance with multiple queries